# Позиционирование элементов внутри div

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня есть `div` внутри которого находится `<p></p>` и `<button></button>`.

Мне нужно чтобы между ними было небольшое расстояние:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать `flex`

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; // распределяет по ширине div
}
```